# Iterate in tree

Tags: swift

I have a tree of nodes, not a binary tree.
The nodes has node children;

```
class Node {
id : String
testable: Bool
children: [Node]
}
```

In this case, the children can have children, and so on.
I need to iterate over the tree, and if a node's testable is true, I need to return the node's id.

If a child's testable is true, I need to return the child's id as well.
I can get the result if I use loops of children/children/children, but it gets very ugly.
Is there a nice clean way of doing it?

Comment: What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: No, not homework :) Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the Node declaration. @vadian 's answer is very promising, and does what it says on the tin. The testable isn't as straight forward as Bool, as shown, but it should work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive function, something like this

```
var ids = [String]()

func testableIDs(node : Node, ids : inout [String]) {
    if node.testable { ids.append( node.id) }
    for child in node.children {
        testableIDs(node: child, ids: &ids)
    }
}
```

It calls itself iterating the children respectively, the ids are collected with an `inout` parameter.